# How to change ovh custom kernel to stock centos7 kernel

Tags: kernel, centos-7

I did try to search for an answer but was not able to find anything about changing the ovh custom kernel to stock kernel for CentOS7. I found how with ubuntu but not CentOS7. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

This was the topic I found on what I would like to do but just for CentOS7.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/871336/switching-from-ovh-kernel-to-default-kernel-without-reinstalling-ubuntu

Comment: Which OVH service? (Dedicated server? KVM? OpenVZ?) They have different answers.

Comment: Dedicated Server ovh.us